# SQL - Count of the associated available records with near Query Geocoder

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-geocoder

I have following models

product.rb

```
has_many :product_warehouses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :available_warehouses, through: :product_warehouses, :source => :warehouse
reverse_geocoded_by "warehouses.latitude", "warehouses.longitude"
```

warehouse.rb

```
has_many :product_warehouses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :products, through: :product_warehouses
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
```

category.rb

```
has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
```

I want to get the count products for particular category. earlier i used below query

```
Category.left_outer_joins(:products).select('categories.*,count(products.id) as products_count').group("categories.id").order("categories.created_at")
```

Now I want to retrieve only available products count in particular category,

**Tried Below Queries**

```
categories =  Product.left_outer_joins(:category,:available_warehouses).near([40.730610, -73.935242], Setting.first&.delivery_within,order: false).group("categories.name").count(:id)

categories = Product.joins("RIGHT OUTER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products.category_id INNER JOIN product_warehouses ON product_warehouses.product_id = products.id INNER JOIN warehouses ON warehouses.id = product_warehouses.warehouse_id").near([40.730610, -73.935242], Setting.first&.delivery_within,order: false).group("categories.name").count(:id)
```

But in this 2 query i am not able to get the category which has 0 products. How can i retrieve the available products count for particular category ?